# What do I do with this Data Extract Error in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

When attempting to save my first Tableau Dashboard to Tableau Public, in order to publicly share, I keep receiving the following error message: "An error occurred while attempting to save the workbook." According to https://help.tableau.com/current/guides/get-started-tutorial/en-us/get-started-tutorial-share.htm this is common but there should be an option in the dialogue box that says "Create Data Extract." I don't have that option, and I'm unsure what to do next? Thanks!

Comment: What is your data source and which version of Tableau are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tableau Desktop (and not the Public version of the editor), you need to create an extract of your data and then you should be able to publish you workbook.

In order to create an extract just right click your source in the upper left part of the editor.

[image]

Doing so, your editor will be ready to publish your workbook on your Public repository.